# Firestore batch deep copy or shallow copy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, deep-copy

Let say I have the following code:

```
let ref1 = db.collection('user').doc('u1')
let ref2 = db.collection('user').doc('u2')

let batch = this.db.batch()
let obj = {foo:'bar'}
batch.set(ref1, obj);
obj.foo = 'not bar anymore'
batch.set(ref2, obj);
batch.commit();
```

Will firestore make a deep copy of `obj` or a shallow copy? In other word, once the query runs and I check my database,  will the value of the document `'u1'` become `{foo:'bar'}`  or `{foo:'not bar anymore bar'}`?

Answer (score 0):

DocumentReference objects are fully immutable (never change) as long as only externally facing APIs are used.  All they really do is point to a document location in Firestore.  Calling set() on a batch doesn't do anything to change the reference passed to it.

Of course, you could try to reach into a DocumentReference to modify it directly, since JavaScript allows such things, but that's not a supported use of the APIs.

Comment: Thank you this information about DocumentReference . Maybe my question was not clear but I what I am really asking is: Will the value stored inside the batch changes if I pass an object as second argument of batch.set then I change a proprety of this object. I edit the question for more clarification.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems like something that should be easy to test.